# adding an object to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

i need to create a hash table that every cell in the array must be a linked list in case of collisions the user can add a char or int type values,

```
Object* createObject(void* data)

{
if (data != NULL)

{

    Object* object = (Object*)malloc(sizeof(Object));
    if (object == NULL)
  return NULL;

     object->data = data;
    object->next = NULL;
    return object;
}
```

}

i have also a function add it takes void* and then creates an object of struct object and inserts it to the list the problem is when i oprint the table it prints address and adds to the list an address

```
int add(Table* table, void* data)





   {

int d = 1;
int key = 0;
int index = 0;
if (table == NULL || data == NULL)
    return -1;


//Object*obj_data=createObject(data);
if (table->Table_tybe == 0)
{
    key = intHashFun((int*)data, table->size);//it returns the hash function int value
}
else
    key = strHashFun((char*)data, table->size);

index = key*d;


Object*tmp = table->arr[index];
Object*obj = tmp;
while (tmp != NULL)
{
    obj = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
if (obj == NULL) {
    table->arr[index] = createObject(data);
    printf("**%d** ", table->arr[index]->data);
    table->arr[index]->next = NULL;

}

else
{

    int j = 0;
    if (obj->next == NULL)
    {
        //tmp->next=createObject(data);
        obj->next = createObject(data);
        obj = obj->next;
        obj->next = NULL;

        return;

    }
```

here are the structs

```
typedef struct Object {
void* data;
struct Object* next;
 }Object;



typedef struct Table {
Object** arr;
int size;
int Table_tybe;
int Table_length;//list length

}Table;

int size = 3;
int listlength = 5;
Table* table = createTable(size, 0, listlength);
int one = 1;


add(table, &one);
```

Comment: Please format your code and your question correctly. And what is your question?

Comment: the queston is when i insert a value to the linked list and try to print it it prints the address

Comment: " int size = 3;
 int listlength = 5;
 Table* table = createTable(size, 0, listlength);
 int one = 1;
 

 add(table, &one);"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Comment: You don't tell us what the problem is. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also, `createObject(&data)` is *very* wrong, as it passes a pointer to the *variable* `data` (a variable which will go out of scope and cease to exist once the function ends).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ya that i did by mistake i corrected it but nothing changed i still have an address in the data value of the list

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code

```
int one = 1;

add(table, &one);
```

you pass the address of the `int` variable `one` via function `add()` to `createObject()` which allocates an `Object` structure and copies the pointer into the object's `data` field, so it's expected that your object contains the address.

If you want to see the value of your sample variable `one` you would have to cast the `void*` pointer to the correct data type, which is `int *` in this case, and dereference the pointer when you want to print it.

```
printf("**%d** ", *(int*)table->arr[index]->data );
```

Another option would be to change your `Object` to actually store an `int` value instead of a `void*` and to dereference the pointer when copying your actual data to the object.

(As others already mentioned, your code contains more problems.)